# as.date creates some NAs in dataset

Tags: r, na, as.date

I have a simple little dataset:

```
> str(SFdischg)
'data.frame':   11932 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ date: Factor w/ 11932 levels "1/01/1985","1/01/1986",..: 97 4409 8697 9677 10069 10461 10853 11245 11637 489 ...
 $ ddmm: Factor w/ 366 levels "01-Apr","01-Aug",..: 1 13 25 37 49 61 73 85 97 109 ...
 $ year: int  1984 1984 1984 1984 1984 1984 1984 1984 1984 1984 ...
 $ cfs : int  1500 1430 1500 1850 1810 1830 1850 1880 1970 1980 ...
```

I would like to have a column of dates so that I can plot temporal data:

```
SFdischg$daymo <- as.Date(SFdischg$ddmm, format="%d-%b")
> summary(SFdischg)
    date            ddmm            year           cfs           daymo           
 1/01/1985:    1   01-Apr :   33   Min.   :1984   Min.   : 172   Min.   :2018-01-01  
 1/01/1986:    1   01-Aug :   33   1st Qu.:1992   1st Qu.: 705   1st Qu.:2018-04-04  
 1/01/1987:    1   01-Jul :   33   Median :2000   Median : 948   Median :2018-07-03  
 1/01/1988:    1   01-Jun :   33   Mean   :2000   Mean   :1374   Mean   :2018-07-02  
 1/01/1989:    1   01-May :   33   3rd Qu.:2008   3rd Qu.:1340   3rd Qu.:2018-10-01  
 1/01/1990:    1   01-Nov :   33   Max.   :2016   Max.   :8100   Max.   :2018-12-31  
 (Other)  :11926   (Other):11734                                 NA's   :8
```

However, `daymo` now has 8 NAs and I can't understand why (and it makes it difficult to plot!). Where does the handful of NAs come from when there is no missing data in `ddmm`? How can I avoid them? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Maybe some of the dates are malformed and can't be converted properly using `as.date()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that some of the factor data you have in the `ddmm` column cannot be parsed correctly into a date.  You may reveal these bad values using:

```
SFdischg$ddmm[is.na(as.Date(SFdischg$ddmm, format="%d-%b"))]
```

Note that since there is no year component in the `ddmm` column, R appears to be automatically assigning the current year 2018 to the date.  Ideally, you should be building your date using source information which includes a year.

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, the offending rows had `19-Feb` as the date.  This implies that these dates were perhaps not even from 2018, which was not a leap year, and whose February had only 28 days.  This illustrates the importance of working with a full set of information when parsing the date, including the year.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the bad values and found that they are all from 29 Feb (duh!) because of a problem in the original Excel file. Also, Excel assigns the current year to ddmm data; the "date" column from my original csv has the correct ddmmyyyy.

Comment: Agreed. But I couldn't figure out how to go from "date" to "daymo" when I wrote this originally, and I'm using the data to plot a 30 year mean based on date...